# Overpass API returns points instead of polygons

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api

I'm able to retrieve geojson using the following call to the Overpass API for [boroughs](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/London_borough_boundaries) in London:

```
import overpass
api = overpass.API()
response = api.get('relation(1811626);>;out;')
```

However the result for each geo is individual coordinates, not a polygon:

```
{"features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [25.292698, 56.7083821],"type": "Point"}, "id": 1347523073, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [25.292627, 56.7080704], "type": "Point"} ... }}
```

Is it possible to have Overpass return polygons instead of coordinates when querying relations? Or will we need to convert the coordinates to polygons.

Comment: Not answer to your question, but that relation does not seem to be in London https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1811626#map=11/56.7028/25.4701.

Comment: Yes apologies for any confusion - included a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pull Geojson directly from OSM / Overpass from what I can tell.

Here's a workaround. First make a request to overpass and return XML. Then convert the XML to Geojson using osm2geojson (originally a JS package but recenlty adapted for PY)

```
import requests
import osm2geojson

response = requests.get('https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:xml][timeout:25];(rel(51800););out geom;')
string = response.text.replace("\n","")
geojson = osm2geojson.xml2geojson(string)
json.dumps(geojson)
```

In my experience making a get request is easier than learning syntax for various python modules (overpy and overpass)

Answer (score 0):

the overpass api should let you do that and export geojson

```
import overpass
api = overpass.API()
result = api.get('way["place"="neighbourhood"](37.964522,-78.573741,38.097572,-78.415126);', responseformat="geojson", verbosity="geom")
```

actually i'm not sure this is a good answer... this just returns a string....